# How to move Excel file from download folder (Default) to project folder in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I can't see any commands to move file from download folder (default) to project folder in Node JS.
I have tried to get commands from [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) but not able to find correct one.

- My file name : file1_02262023_0512.xlsx
- Folder name: Default download folder

Also I would like to pass the Excel name file1_02262023_* when move to project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js provides two built-in libraries to help with file manipulation: ***fs*** for file system operations and ***path*** for extracting file names. You can use fs to move the file and path to get the file name.
Here's a short example that demonstrates how to move a file from the Downloads folder to the Projects folder.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const oldPath = path.join("..path to the download folder", 
   "excelFile.xlsx");
const newPath = path.join(__dirname, "someFolder", "excelFile.xlsx");

const moveFile = (oldPath, newPath) => {
  /**
   * here we can add a check if the file and the folder exist
   * fs.existsSync(oldPath) - check if the file exists
   * fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(newPath), { recursive: true }); - check if 
   * the folder exists
   */
  
  // copy the .xlsx file to the new folder
  fs.renameSync(oldPath, newPath);
 };

 const getTheFileName = (oldPath) => {
   return path.split("\\").pop();
 };
```